# Android How to store spanned text in shared preferences

Tags: android, html, sharedpreferences, spanned

the Html parse is very slow, so I thought of storing a static text within the sharded preferences to access it faster. Is it possible to store this somehow and retrieve it, so that it can be set without usage of Html.fromHtml?

This way I would just parse the file one time. Once it is in cache it should be much faster, if no parsing is required.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can store Static string in shared preferences.

Here is code which may help you..

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();        
editor.putString(YOUR_KEY, YOUR_STATIC_STRING);
editor.commit();
```

Comment: Hello, the text contains HTML specifics. If I cast it to string the link is away. I did a workaround, where I store a large blob of data. And add the second part, which contains html text. the second part, I read in at any time. The first part is put in a shared preference. If someone, knows how to get a string of the spanned type containing all information, this would help me a lot.

Comment: can you please put your code here?? b'coz I can't understood your comment. I think in android your HTML specifics is also string consideration. If you have HTML text in file than you have to store file rather than String.